# incorrect labels in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, coordinates, axis-labels

I have a dataframe:

```
   key    year flag     amount   pct   pos
   <chr> <int> <lgl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A      2017 TRUE  13870255. 0.487 0.244
 2 A      2017 FALSE 14609185. 0.513 0.744
 3 B      2017 TRUE  23562809. 0.807 0.403
 4 B      2017 FALSE  5641352. 0.193 0.903
 5 C      2017 TRUE  22683017. 0.772 0.386
 6 C      2017 FALSE  6686562. 0.228 0.886
 7 D      2017 TRUE  14840593. 0.500 0.250
 8 D      2017 FALSE 14846822. 0.500 0.750
 9 A      2018 FALSE 16131222. 0.485 0.242
10 A      2018 TRUE  17155225. 0.515 0.742
```

I have created wrapepd pied plots with percentage labels inside each plot - highlighted inside trhe black box. The first plot in the left-upper corner seems to be correct, but then the middle-upped plot has inverserd colors - surface for 51.54% is smaller than surface for 48.46%.
How can the labels be fixed such that the surface corresponds to the percantage?

[image]

code used for ggplot:

```
ggplot(valuesDT, aes(x=1,y=pct,fill=flag)) +
          geom_bar(stat="identity",width=2)+
          coord_polar(theta='y')+
          theme_classic()+
          theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.title=element_blank(),
                axis.line.y = element_blank(),
                axis.line.x = element_blank(),
            axis.text.y = element_blank(), panel.grid  = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_blank(),
            plot.title = element_text(color="blue", size=16, face="bold")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "green"), labels = c("F", "non-T"), name = "")+
  geom_text(aes(y = pos, label = paste0(round(pct*100, digits = 2), " %")), size = 3)+
  facet_grid(key ~ year)
```

Which looks alright. But then i noticed that the labels were not correct

data:

```
structure(list(key = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "D", "D"), year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L
), flag = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), amount = c(13870254.87, 
14609184.5199999, 23562809.1300003, 5641352.16999989, 22683016.61, 
6686562.28999991, 14840593.21, 14846822.3, 16131221.89, 17155224.79, 
26853512.1700003, 6337822.7600002, 26324941.5199999, 7775499.19999981, 
16527294.6700001, 18136429.54, 18660941.7799999, 19628554.06, 
29955135.69, 7154960.09000001, 28728476.97, 8923411.36999992, 
18634207.47, 18495786.62), pct = c(0.487026962857644, 0.512973037142356, 
0.806830536509883, 0.193169463490117, 0.772330331573125, 0.227669668426875, 
0.499895088711952, 0.500104911288048, 0.484618320635959, 0.515381679364041, 
0.809051887386679, 0.190948112613322, 0.771982442577655, 0.228017557422345, 
0.476789353904222, 0.523210646095778, 0.487364520493513, 0.512635479506487, 
0.807196399265127, 0.192803600734873, 0.763002288506204, 0.236997711493796, 
0.501864003124596, 0.498135996875404), pos = c(0.243513481428822, 
0.743513481428822, 0.403415268254941, 0.903415268254941, 0.386165165786563, 
0.886165165786563, 0.249947544355976, 0.749947544355976, 0.24230916031798, 
0.742309160317979, 0.404525943693339, 0.904525943693339, 0.385991221288828, 
0.885991221288828, 0.238394676952111, 0.738394676952111, 0.243682260246756, 
0.743682260246756, 0.403598199632564, 0.903598199632563, 0.381501144253102, 
0.881501144253102, 0.250932001562298, 0.750932001562298)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), groups = structure(list(year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L
), key = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", 
"C", "D"), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10, 11:12, 
    13:14, 15:16, 17:18, 19:20, 21:22, 23:24), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with `group` enabled by `key` in your `aes()`. Here the code and in the plot you can see how areas are properly placed about what you mentioned in the question:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
ggplot(valuesDT, aes(x=1,y=pct,fill=flag,group=key)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=2)+
  coord_polar(theta='y')+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), panel.grid  = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(color="blue", size=16, face="bold")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "green"), labels = c("non-T","F"), name = "")+
  geom_text(aes(y = pos, label = paste0(round(pct*100, digits = 2), " %")), size = 3)+
  facet_grid(key ~ year)
```

Output:

[image]

Also, be careful on how you assign the labels, without using the `scale_fill_*()` option this is the output:

```
#Code 2
ggplot(valuesDT, aes(x=1,y=pct,fill=flag,group=key)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=2)+
  coord_polar(theta='y')+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), panel.grid  = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(color="blue", size=16, face="bold")) +
  # scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "green"), labels = c("non-T","F"), name = "")+
  geom_text(aes(y = pos, label = paste0(round(pct*100, digits = 2), " %")), size = 3)+
  facet_grid(key ~ year)
```

Output:

[image]

And it can be seen that percentages and areas are placed properly.